# Transmit or Simulate SMS-CB (Short Messaging Service-Cell Broadcast)

Tags: networking, mobile, sms, cellular-network

Can a cell phone transmit [SMS-CB (Short Messaging Service-Cell Broadcast)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) ? 
If not, Can I get a device that can transmit SMS-CB messages ?  
Else, Is there a good simulator that can simulate SMS-CB transmission and receiving mobile phones ? 

Thank You


*NOTE: Cell Broadcast (SMS-CB) is designed for simultaneous delivery of messages to multiple users in a specified area. For example, information such as Location, Tower name, Ads or Emergency messages can be transmitted.*

Answer (score 7):

Technically, the SMS-CB messages originate at a device called "Cell Broadcast Centre (CBC)", which is part of the network operators equipment. It sends the SMS-CB through the Base Station Controller (BSC). This cannot be done over the air, it is something which happens inside the mobile operators network. It would probably be too much to explain all GSM/3G/UMTS network components here, you might want to read up on mobile network architecture.

So the simple answer is no, a handset (mobile phone) cannot directly send SMS-CB messages.

Now the question is, how to tell the CBC to send an SMS-CB to some network cells. There exist some standardized interfaces for that, which are used for emergency alerting, e.g. the [Commercial Mobile Alert System (CMAS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_Mobile_Alert_System) in the US. If these interfaces are designed sensibly, they cannot be abused by just about anyone using a mobile handset. But I would not be surprised if there were security gaps in some operator's networks which would allow unauthorized parties to send SMS-CB, e.g. via insecure Internet/SS7 gateways. But that is wild speculation. Normally, it should not be possible to send unauthorized SMS-CB from outside of the operator's network.

Comment: Can I use a computer and/or some GSM/Radio hardware interface to obtain a communication system similar to SMS-CB ? What about Simulating SMS-CB using some simulators ?

Comment: Of course you can have your own SMS-CB, but unless you also run your own network / your own base station, you will not have much fun with a standalone SMS-CB. It needs to talk to a BSC in order to do it's job. By the way, OpenBTS supports SMS-CB.